# export 3d model compatibles with irrlicht

Tags: 3dsmax, 3d-modelling, irrlicht, cinema-4d

I'm making a 3d game as a school project, with `irrlicht` engine. To do this, I'm searching for good 3d models. I found some but I could only get them in recents formats (`c4d`, `fbx` or `blend`). Of course it is possible to export them in `.x` or `.3ds`, but in this case, they lose their animations. Does someone knows a way to convert `c4d`, `bfx` or `blend` to a format handled by irrlicht, and keep their animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use b3d models with Irrlicht.
You can convert .blend files with blender using a script you can install into blender.

https://github.com/alrusdi/blender-b3d-exporter/blob/master/b3d_export.py

If you don't want to bother converting files you can find free b3d models at sites like this:

http://3drt.com/store/free-downloads/free-characters/